# Problem with creating github release via travis-ci with body content

Tags: github, travis-ci, continuous-deployment, github-release

I need help or explanation in deployment to github releases via Travis-CI

I have part of `.travis.yml` configuration file

```
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: publish
      if: env(BRANCH_IS_TAG) != true
      name: "Create Github Release"
      script:
        - yarn build
        - bash ./prepare-publish.sh
      deploy:
        provider: releases
        name: "Release ${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
        body: "test \n test \r\n + /r/n *"
        overwrite: true
        skip_cleanup: true
        api_key:
          secure: ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
        file:
          - release.zip
        on:
          all_branches: true
          repo: acacode/stonex
```

This part of config works fine while I'm not changing this line

```
  body: "test \n test \r\n + /r/n *"
```

To

```
  body: "${GIT_LOG}"
```

This variable is creating before deploy part in `prepare-publish.sh` script

```
export GIT_LOG=$(git cherry -v develop)
```

And output it:

[image]

When I attach this variable to body Travis says me

```
   invalid option "--body="
```

travis configuration file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/acacode/stonex/internal/travis-ci-builds/.travis.yml

travis build log with this problem:
https://travis-ci.org/acacode/stonex/builds/524606655#L543

script which contain the `$GIT_LOG` variable:
https://github.com/acacode/stonex/blob/internal/travis-ci-builds/prepare-publish.sh

*Hope on your help, thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like passing the `body` option is an existing bug in `travis-ci` deploys that hasn't been fixed yet: https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/155

Comment: Yes, you are right! But also my config have a couple additional problems like creating environment variables inside child bash scripts and use them inside travis config. If someone will want to do the same things like publishing on github releases via Travis. Better to use custom scripts on nodejs or ruby